# ES6 detect if a function is on prototype chain of a class instance

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, prototype, es6-class

Given an ES6 class:

```
class C {
  x () { }
  fnIsMethodOfC (fn) { return /* ? */ }
}
```

and a variety of functions such as

```
function y () {}
z = () => {}
```

Is there an efficient way to determine if a function is a method of C i.e.

```
c = new C()
c.fnIsMethodOfC(c.x) === true
c.fnIsMethodOfC(C.prototype.x) === true
c.fnIsMethodOfC(y) === false
c.fnIsMethodOfC(z) === false
```

I know one could recursively loop through the prototype chain, but that would be an expensive operation.

Linking related questions:

- [JavaScript ES6: Test for arrow function, built-in function, regular function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222228)
- [Determine if a JavaScript function is a bound function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686850)
- [ES6 Iterate over class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881632)

Comment: Do you just want to check functions the class implements itself or all functions in the Prototype chain?

Comment: If name match is sufficient could do `Object.getOwnPropertyNames( C.prototype ).includes(fn.name)`.

Comment: @LucaKiebel An ideal answer would check the chain, but a suitable start would be just what the class implements.

Comment: If you don't know the method name, then no you will have to search for it.

Comment: "*One could recursively loop through the prototype chain, but that would be an expensive operation.*" - why do you think that?

Comment: @bergi The size of the prototype chain is a known unknown, with an `O(n)` lookup over the cumulative number of methods in the chain.  This may be large, especially for a lookup that's in an inner-loop.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt Yes, of course you would need to look at all properties if you don't know the name, but there's nothing that makes following the prototype chain especially expensive.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt Also, what's the actual problem you are trying to solve with this detection? I can't imagine where the check would be performance-sensitive.

Comment: @Bergi It's part of the [lifecycle](https://github.com/knockout/tko/blob/master/packages/lifecycle/src/LifeCycle.js#L44) for TKO/Knockout.js that is the base class for binding handlers and components. For some apps lifecycle computeds can be created hundreds of thousands of times a second, so uncached `O(n)` lookups might create performance barriers.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt I see, it is part of "when it's a method then bind it" magic. However, if that code runs thousands of times per second, you shouldn't create those many bound functions in the first place. Bind it once, then pass in the bound method every time you call `computed`. (Disclaimer: I never worked with Knockout)

Comment: Thanks @Bergi.  The `computed` call is user-facing, so we've no control, but pre-binding is a good tip so I'll note it in the docs re. performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option may be:

```
class C {
  fnIsMethodOfC (fn) {
    const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this)
    return proto && proto[fn.name] === fn
  }
}
```

Comment: The `fn.name` may work for methods declared in a `class`, but not in general for all methods.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, a better answer would be comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
class C {
  fnIsMethodOfC (fn) {
    if(!fn || !fn.name) return false;
    return !!this[fn.name] && fn === this[fn.name];
  }
}
```

This will also add addtional check if the actual function is different.

Comment: fixed it.. it should have been fn.name