# Set this for required arrow-functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrow-functions

I'm trying to set `this` in various scenarios.

The following code executed in node.js `v6.8.1` will print what is commented at the end of each line:

```
function requireFromString(src) {
  var Module = module.constructor;
  var m = new Module();
  m._compile(src, __filename);
  return m.exports;
}

(function(){
  var f1 = (() => {console.log(this.a === 1)});
  var f2 = function(){ console.log(this.a === 1) };
  var f3 = requireFromString('module.exports = (() => {console.log(this.a === 1)});');
  var f4 = requireFromString('module.exports = function(){ console.log(this.a === 1) };');

  console.log('Body:');
  console.log(this.a === 1);                          // true
  (()=>console.log(this.a === 1))();                  // true
  (()=>console.log(this.a === 1)).call(this);         // true
  (function(){console.log(this.a === 1)})();          // false
  (function(){console.log(this.a === 1)}).call(this); // true


  console.log('\nFunctions:');
  f1();                                               // true
  f1.call(this);                                      // true
  f2();                                               // false
  f2.call(this);                                      // true
  f3();                                               // false [1]
  f3.call(this);                                      // false [2]
  f4();                                               // false 
  f4.call(this);                                      // true

}).apply({a:1});
```

With the documentation for [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) I can explain all cases except the ones labelled with `[1]` and `[2]`.

Can somebody shed some light on the observed behaviour? And maybe give a hint how I can call `f3` so that the function prints true.

---

**Notes**

- The `requireFromString`-function is adapted from [Load node.js module from string in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581830/load-node-js-module-from-string-in-memory) and is just a hack to slim down this stackoverflow question. In practice this is replaced by an ordinary `require(...)`

Comment: The point of an arrow function is to inherit the value of `this` from the lexical context.  If that's not what you want, then don't use an arrow function.  If you want to "set" or "control" the value of `this`, then use a regular function call and one of the various methods available (`.apply()`, `.call()`, `obj.method()`, etc...) for controlling the value of `this` in that function call.

Comment: Do you have the expcted behaviour when you call the `f4();` and the `f4.call(this);`?

Comment: to give you some context: I'm refactoring [FluentFlow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluentflow) which uses user-supplied functions, so called 'matchers'.  As [detecting arrow functions seems to be hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222228/javascript-es6-test-for-arrow-function-built-in-function-regular-function) (and I don't like the accepted answer) I want to set `this` for the 'matcher' no matter what kind of function is provided.

Comment: even more context: [this is how a matcher should be defiend by the user](https://github.com/Enteee/FluentFlow/blob/kill-deasync/test/matcherTest.js#L10) and  [this is how the matcher is called by FluentFlow](https://github.com/Enteee/FluentFlow/blob/kill-deasync/core/matcher.js#L79), yes: i do know that i could simply pass obj as a parameter. But I do like the readability of the `this` version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because "fat arrow functions" always take their `this` lexically, from the surrounding code. They ***cannot*** have their `this` changed with `call`, `bind`, etc. Run this code as an example:

```
var object = {
  stuff: 'face',

  append: function() {
    return (suffix) => {
      console.log(this.stuff + ' '+suffix);
    }
  }
}
var object2 = {
  stuff: 'foot'
};

object.append()(' and such');
object.append().call(object2, ' and such');
```

You will only see `face and such`.

So, as far as why that doesn't work in the case of `f3`, it's because it's a self-contained module being required. Therefore, it's base-level arrow functions will only use the `this` in the module, they cannot be bound with `bind`, `call`, etc etc as discussed.
**In order to use `call` on them, they must be regular functions, not arrow functions.**

---

What does "lexical `this`" mean? *It basically works the same as a closure.* Take this code for example:

fileA.js:

```
(function () {
    var info = 'im here!';

    var infoPrintingFunctionA = function() {
        console.log(info);
    };

    var infoPrintingFunctionB = require('./fileB');

    infoPrintingFunctionA();
    infoPrintingFunctionB();
})();
```

fileB.js:

```
module.exports = function() {
    console.log(info);
};
```

What will be the result? An error, `info is not defined`. Why? Because the accessible variables (the scope) of a function only includes the variables that are available *where the function is defined*. Therefore, `infoPrintingFunctionA` has access to `info` because `info` exists in the scope where `infoPrintingFunctionA` is defined.

However, even though `infoPrintingFunctionB` is being *called* in the same scope, it was not *defined* in the same scope. Therefore, it cannot access variables from the calling scope.

But this all has to do with the variables and closures; what about `this` and arrow functions?

**The `this` of arrow functions works the same as the closure of other variables in functions**. Basically, an arrow function is just saying to include `this` in the closure that is created. And in the same way you couldn't expect the variables of fileA to be accessible to the functions of fileB, you can't expect the `this` of the calling module (fileA) to be able to be referenced from the body of the called module (fileB).

TLDR: How do we define "surrounding code", in the expression "lexical `this` is taken from the surrounding code?" The surrounding code is the scope where the function is defined, not necessarily where it is called.

Comment: can you please further elaborate "So, as far as why that doesn't work in the case of f3, it's because it's a self-contained module being required." ? Why is `this` in this case not taken from the surrounding code?

Comment: @Ente I updated the answer with some additional clarification, let me know if it helps.

Comment: thank you `this` helps ;) So I'm back to [detecting arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222228/javascript-es6-test-for-arrow-function-built-in-function-regular-function) and raising exceptions if one is supplied.