# How to enumerate all arrow functions defined in a js module (not globally)?

Tags: javascript, module

Suppose I have several arrow functions:

```
const a = (b, c) => { // body
}

const b = (g, f) => { // body
}

module.exports = { a }
```

Now I'd like to have references to all this module's functions (not only exported ones as 'a' function but 'b' function also)
How to make something like
`const functionsArray = module...keys()` (what should be here?)
How to do this inside this module?

Comment: Why only arrow functions?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222228/javascript-es6-test-for-arrow-function-built-in-function-regular-function

Comment: What environment are you working in? It's impossible to inspect the scope of a module from outside. Are you getting the module code as a string and want to statically analyse it? What is your goal, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Barmar Perhaps most complicated case. (I use them often)

Comment: Why do you think arrow functions would be any more complicated to find than other functions?

Comment: If there's a way to get all the names defined in a module, loop over them and check whether `typeof x == "function"`

Comment: @Bergi I'd like to get this functions list inside module.

Comment: @Barmar That'll do :) But I don't know how

Comment: @Bergi I need this to automatically make proxies for them (for logging)

Comment: @skl Don't use proxies, use wrapping decorators. Apply them explicitly on each function you want to log - `const a = withLogging("a", (b, c) => { … });`. There is no other way to achieve this dynamically from within the module code, especially with `const` declarations. If you need this to be automatic, you will need to use a transpiler (static code transformation) to inject the logging code.

Comment: @skl have you found the solution?